# Submitting jobs with sequential completion

Tags: shell-script, job-control

If I have numerous jobs that rely on environment variables, how can I submit them sequentially? Here is my attempt that has not been working, week 6 is always submitted (and finishes) before week 5.

```
#!/bin/sh

(export id=me;
 export pass=welcome;
 export week=5;
 sas -log $HOME/logs/log$week.log sasjob.sas > /dev/null;
 export week=6;
 sas -log $HOME/logs/log$week.log sasjob.sas > /dev/null;
) &
```

I need the statements to run in exact sequential order on **completion**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly the following should do it:

```
for week in 5 6 ; do
    id=me pass=welcome week=$week \
        sas -log "$HOME/logs/log${week}.log" sasjob.sas
done >/dev/null &
```

Comment: I am still having difficulty getting this to work, I suspect because the job is that is being exited with jobcode 0 is really the submission of the script to sas... not the actual job itself. Do you see a reason this would/would not be the case?

Comment: @mkemp6 - I'm sorry but I don't really. I was just trying to help. What happens if you remove the `&` and wrap the whole thing in `{ ... ; } &`? As far as `sas` goes in particular, I'm a deadend for info there. I can usually help to some degree with shell stuff, but not much otherwise.